# jquery returns 0 when reading a negative from value in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery, and stumbled across some unexpected results today.   When selecting the value from an LI element using jquery, IE will return a 0 if the value is negative instead of the correct value.    In Chrome, the code below will throw up an alert with a -1, but in IE it says 0.   Any thoughts?

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                alert(this.value);      
            });
        });
   </script>

    <ol>
        <li class="ui-selected" value="-1" />
    </ol>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp - value is a deprecated optional attribute to the LI tag that let you specify the value of an ordered list.  Given that I'd switch to using data-value or something similar as noted below by @Josiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really using jQuery to get the value. I don't know why IE is behaving that way, but I'd say give it a try using <s>`.attr()`, or</s> the native `getAttribute` to get the value.

```
alert( $(this).attr('value') );
```

```
alert( this.getAttribute('value') );
```

---

[@Josiah Ruddell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39013/josiah-ruddell) noted that `.attr()` didn't work.

Comment: @patric - `.attr('value')` didn't seem to change the result.

Comment: @Josiah: Did you try `getAttribute`? I can't get to IE right now.

Comment: getAttribute did the trick -- I now get the correct result in IE.    Is that typical to have to use getAttribute instead of just going to value directly?

Comment: @adamnickerson: Not necessarily. There are many valid attributes that map directly to a property. I don't know enough about the `value` attribute for `<li>` to know why IE is returning `0`. May just be a bug. If you're going to be updating the property, you may need to use `setAttribute` to satisfy IE. I'd be sure to do some testing.

Comment: @patrick: Using a custom attribute name other than 'value' worked fine in IE for me whilst using `.attr()`

Comment: @conquenator: jQuery's `.attr()` method muddles the distinction between attributes and properties a bit. Not sure if it first looks for a property or an attribute. I'm guessing that if it finds a property it uses that first, which is why your custom `myVar` attribute worked, because it didn't map to a property.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the reason, however value is not an attribute of list item elements. If you need a custom value use a `data-value` attribute (or other).

See this example for more information [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BG6uT/1/)

```
<ul>
    <li value="-1" data-value="-1"></li>
</ul>

$('li').each(function(){
    alert(this.value); // 0
    alert($(this).attr('data-value')); // -1
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `value` isn't an attribute/property of `li` elements. I get a value of `0` when an `li` doesn't have any `value` attribute set. http://jsfiddle.net/znNaN/ Seems to imply that an `li` can/does have a `value` for some reason.

Comment: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/li) shows a value attribute. Hmmm... Never knew it

Comment: +1 For your `data-` suggestion assuming OP meant to use a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** don't use 'value' use any other attribute name.
See the updated [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Bbx/2/)

Even if `"value"` isn't a valid HTML attribute jQuery doesn't recognize this and its attribute selectors work just fine.

There isn't such a thing as an invalid selector. It either returns something or doesn't.

```
<ul>
    <li  class="ui-selected" myVar="-1" >
        Hi
    </li>
</ul>



$(".ui-selected").each(function(){
    var liValue =  $(this).attr('myVar');
    var intVal = parseInt(liValue); 
    // Just to be safe you've retrieved only an integer!

    alert(liValue);
});
```

Comment: IE gives you -1 when using `.attr()`?

Comment: Well yes, but your original answer stated `value`, and the question was about getting the expected value from the `value` property.